# How to wire sennheiser headphones to an iphone headphone cable

Tags: audio, wiring, iphone

I have a pair of [these](http://www.sennheiser.co.uk/uk/home_en.nsf/root/private_headsets_mobile_music_502555) (or something very similar) :

The plug failed so I chopped it off and was hoping to wire it to a plug on a spare pair of iPhone headphones I had kicking around. Both sets of headphones have a button and microphone so I figured it wouldn't be too hard.

I was wrong. The iPhone cable has 6 wires (one white one hiding inside the red/green combo) and the sennheiser only has 4 - white, red and two coppers. I did a very quick test to see if just holding some of the wires together would give me sound in one of the ear-pieces - nothing, though I'm confident both cables are fine.

Is this maybe to do with laminate on the wires themselves? Do I need to connect red to red *and* a ground? I'm a noob so don't know what a ground does in  audio cabling.

I would appreciate any pointers. My plan is to twist the wires together (like this - [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mSNCuZ9hho)) rather than solder. I also have some heat-shrink tubing.

There is a diagram of iphone pinouts [here](http://pinouts.ru/HeadsetsHeadphones/iphone_headphone_pinout.shtml) -

here are my cables:

[sennheiser](http://cl.ly/0S3N1l1U03280f0R123U)
[iphone](http://cl.ly/0h1X08122H2W1o2s2h34)

Comment: This sounds like a consumer electronics question to me.

Answer (score 2):

well, in general, you should have right, left, and mic, with a ground for each on the iphone end, and all 3 will have a common ground. for the headphones, right and left, with a ground for each, and ground is shared.

you will want to remove the protective coating with a microtorch or other heat source,  solder and heatshrink, as opposed to twist together. You will also want to look up the pinout for the iphone side of it, and  use a continuity tester to identify what each cable usually is.

red is USUALLY right, blue or green is is usually left - the white on the sennheiser is unusual (i double check this either by following the cable to the end, or using  a temporary connection with crocodile clips between a prepared, tinned end of the headphone cable and jack).

Red to red, white to green, and 'copper' to 'copper' should do the trick. all 3 have the pesky coating, so you'll need to remove it.

[this is the exact](http://www.instructables.com/id/Replacing-the-jack-on-a-pair-of-headphones/) process/tools that have worked for me in the past - but instead of the jack, tin both ends, press to check, then solder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - this page has some labels for the wires. http://www.zerologic.com/blog/iPhone-Headphone-plug-pinouts.html

Comment: It also has the comment 'The mic requires the white wire inside the red and green combo to joined separately.'

Comment: Do you think this tester would do the job? http://www.maplin.co.uk/3-in-1-e-tester-46020?c=froogle&u=46020&t=module

Comment: yup. and multimeters are VERY useful in general

Comment: Looking at the pic in my first comment, do you think its (iphone)red->red(senn), (iphone)green->white(senn), (iphone)red/green & two coppers -> (senn)one of the coppers(needs testing) ? Bit confused about how the mic is going to connect.

Comment: which copper shouldn't matter - they're connected to the same part of the jack in most common setups. my guess is the red/green is the ground for the mic, and the white is the signal for the mic, and they connect to the mic on one end, and the trrs on the other.