# Convert Iphone 3.5mm pin to standartd Samsung Android 3.5mm pin

Tags: adapter, iphone, speakers, converter, impedance-matching

This is a simple question. 
I want the new Iphone EarPod to work with Samsung/Nokia phones. 
I tried to use the headphone to Samsung phones. [Here is the result](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29460/would-apple-earpods-work-on-my-android-phone/45020#45020)

Here is the [Universal 4-pole Cell Phone headset pinout](http://pinoutsguide.com/HeadsetsHeadphones/blackberry_9700_headset_pinout.shtml), the one which Samsung/Nokia make.
[image]

Now the question is:

1. How can I make a converter/adapter for the pin to work well with Iphone EarPad? (I don't want to cut the wire and check which wire works for which function)
2. Is there a way to make a simple circuit within the connector which makes the impedance match?

I'm really not in the electrical engineering field, so please consider me as an absolute beginner.

I don't care whether the play/pause/vol.up/vol.down functions works or not. I'll consider it as an added advantage if it is possible. :) But I need mic & the speakers to work well.

Comment: Essentially, some Android phones have a L/R/Mic/Gnd setup while the iphone has L/R/Gnd/Mic. Switch those two pins around (3 and 4) and you should get the mic and the play/stop button to work. The Next/Prev button or volume control are not as simple.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it.. What about the impedance matching?

Comment: Related Qn : [How to wire sennheiser headphones to an iphone headphone cable?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18208/how-to-wire-sennheiser-headphones-to-an-iphone-headphone-cable)

Comment: Related Qn : [Electronic aspects of iPhone 3.5mm audio output.](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38452/electronic-aspects-of-iphone-3-5mm-audio-output)

Comment: You said the sound works fine for the headset. So why do you care about impedance-matching?

Comment: Yeah, I could hear it properly. But as far as I read, power transfer depends on impedance matching. Won't it affect the exact volume levels or even the earphone itself, may be when I use max volume of the phone? Or should I neglect the impedance matching part?

Comment: Ignore it. As long as it's close enough (you're not trying to drive 4Ω speakers or 600Ω headphones), you will be fine. You might not get the full volume range, but sometimes those volume ranges can cause permanent hearing damage anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, some Android phones have a L/R/Mic/Gnd setup while the iphone has L/R/Gnd/Mic. Switch those two pins around (3 and 4) and you should get the mic and the play/stop button to work. The Next/Prev button or volume control are not as simple. – Passerby May 9 '13 at 3:40